# HQL query throws an EJB Exception

Tags: jakarta-ee, hql

I am tryin to write a hql that queries two tables that are related on a one to many Relationship but there is an error on execution.

```
String status = "VACANT";
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Beds 
    WHERE status=:status INNER JOIN Rooms on Beds.roomId=Rooms.id   
    WHERE Rooms.hostelId=:hostelId");

    query.setParameter("status", status);
    query.setParameter("hostelId", hostelId);
    List result = query.getResultList();

    return ((Long)result.get(0)).intValue();
```

The error that is trown

> javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:
>   JOIN near line 1, column 67 [select count(id) from
>   portal.beds.model.Beds where status=:status JOIN Rooms ON
>   Beds.roomId=Rooms.id WHERE Rooms.hostelId=:hostelId]

Comment: You have 2 `WHERE` clauses. The query should probably be something like `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Beds INNER JOIN Rooms on Beds.roomId=Rooms.id WHERE Rooms.hostelId=:hostelId AND status=:status`.

Comment: thanks Nikos, lemme test that